# The correct fluid level for this brake reservoir

Tags: brakes, reservoir, peugeot-405

I have problem identifying the correct fluid level for this reservoir. There is no clear max mark on it and I don't know whether it is currently over-filled or not.[image]

The blue line you see in the above picture is just the extension of the letter A.
The car in question is a Peugeot 405. The one shown in the owner's manual is different from this reservoir.

Comment: Did you examine the left side of the brake fluid reservoir, adjacent to the cap?

Comment: @F Dryer - I'll have a look.

Comment: @F Dryer - I checked both left and right sides of the reservoir as well but couldn't find anything that resembles Max mark. I wish there was a method to let me know whether  it is overfilled or not.

Comment: Here's a Haynes manual link to download a free pdf. Page -13 shows images of the brake fluid reservoir and where the min/max levels are on the side closest to the cap. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://diagramas.diagramasde.com/automoviles/Haynes%2520Peugeot%2520405%2520Service%2520And%2520Repair%2520Manual.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwimv6jSrq31AhVriOAKHXl-A2kQFnoECAMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1WNEMqp4HyWodHSJhsqPne